# What does "reveal" do from, e.g., the services menu?

Tags: macos, services

"Reveal" seems to be an alternate action to "open" - except it just opens some random thing that I have no control over. For example, "revealing" a ruby file in the Finder opens Path Finder (the third party Finder replacement).

So, what's it supposed to do? Can I have any control over how it functions?

I'm on Mountain Lion, but I *think* this is a long-standing action.

Comment: I don't have the reveal option in my services menu in ML 10.8.2 Is it possible you installed it as an auxiliary service together with some application? If it's an Automator service you could do a system search to find the "reveal" service, open it and see what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Bart: An option in the Services menu is shown only when it applies to the selected item.  Use "Services Preverences" at the bottom to get the listing of all services.

Comment: I see, I do have it checked in my Service Preference, but when I select a file or folder in the Finder it does not show in the Services menu. I failed to find the Reveal service as a separate file though.

Comment: The explanation for this is likely that you haven't installed PathFinder (see below). Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Pathfinder feature that's designed to bring up the contents of your current Finder window in Pathfinder.  There's no documentation for Pathfinder, so you'd have to check with their support team to see if it could do something different.